C# Thread Affinity Mask for 256 processor count
My computer has Enviroment.ProcessorCount = 256. I need to set a Thread Affinity mask for the group of 64-127 + 192-255. How can I do that?
Int will not be able to represent that Mask. Any suggestion to solve my problem?

What version of Windows are you running? Microsoft made changes in Win11 / WS2022 to better handle 128+ CPU core scenarios.

There's no code or explanation of what you want except the tag. Is the actual question how to use P/Invoke with the SetThreadAffinityMask function? As the docs say: On a system with more than 64 processors, the affinity mask must specify processors in the thread's current processor group..

What's the actual problem you want to solve? The related docs talk about Processor Groups, CPU Sets and NUMA processors. If you want your application's threads to use a single node you need more than just calling SetThreadAffinityMask

I am using Linux OS. Basically I need to set the affinity of the long running threads I run to specific cores. They have set up a node for low latency (possessors 0-63 and 128-191) where network card is also "attached". All my long running threads should be running on that processors and the other OS threads should not run on those to avoid interference.
